# Level selection view - similiar to Angry Bird's

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I am making game and need to prepare view for level selection. Could you recommend me some opensource library which could I use? I need icons to vibrate after long pressing one of them, some callbacks after choosing them, possibility to prepare custom icon's view, page control and horizontal scrolling. I was trying to use OpenSpringBoard but weirdly couldn't see scrollview and pagecontrol working in this project - it seems that there's possibility to use only one page. On the other hand, myLauncher(https://github.com/dlinsin/myLauncher) isn't so easy to include in project, as I need a seperate view with some delegate methods.

I need to be compatible with >iOS 4.2

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you are making a game you really should use some graphic engine like [cocos-2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) (which uses opengl for rendering) and not using standard iOs views.

Here an example the angry bird menu done with cocos-2d : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kZ_d_B-PjyY